# Is there still a need for Project Update Thursday?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat

The weekly PUT meetings have been fizzling lately, mostly because many of the regulars are busy with our lives. Do we still need to have a PUT, should it be changed (new time?), or is there something else we should be doing to attract more regulars to the chat (and to the blog)? If there's no interest in PUT anymore, I'm tempted to let it end and just encourage people drop in whenever they'd like to ask questions. But if there's something that can be done to bring it back to life, then I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Maybe PUT is better as a Spring/Summer event, since participation seems to trail off as the weather gets worse.

Comment: Or it could go once a month.  First or last Thursday of the month.

Comment: Maybe it's time to take PUT and the blog out behind the barn.

Comment: I never understood the concept of "the blog isn't used enough, so we must destroy it." Even if it gets used a couple times a year, it's nice to have a place to put the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going for a compromise right now. I'm making PUT only 15 minutes long so that it's more likely to stay on topic. And if no one has any updates, that week's PUT gets closed up and no bookmark is created. If anyone objects and would like to take over running PUT another way, I'm happy to hand over the reigns and take a back seat on this one.